# Node Package Summary Badges

Tags: node.js, npm

As I learn about Node.js, one thing that has jumped out of me is the use of badges on the package pages. An example of such badges can be seen [here](https://npmjs.org/package/xmldom). The badges I'm referring to are the build status, coverage, and npm module number. I'm curious about these badges.

Are these badges all provided by a single entity? Or, is this just a standard format that various entities have decided to standardize on? Are there other informational badges available?

Thank you!

Comment: Here is another: http://nodei.co

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're just images provided by some CI (continuous integration) systems, [in this case Travis CI.](http://about.travis-ci.org/docs/user/status-images/) Other CI systems, [like Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Embeddable+Build+Status+Plugin), provide badges too; they're meant specifically for embedding. There's no "standard format."

I imagine they're inspired by real-life [build light indicators.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_light_indicator)